# Service Bus for Windows - Performance and Scalability

Tags: message-queuing, messaging, bus

We are building out a system using Service Bus for Windows 1.1 for pub/sub. If we were on Azure, we could use partitioning to scale it out. However, the on-premise version does not support partitioning. Instead, all nodes in a farm seem to use the same SQL Server for their persistence layer, and this seems to be a built-in bottleneck.

What can we do to get the Service Bus for Windows to scale out?